# How to validate Spring @PathVariable properties first?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have the following `PUT` method in my Spring Controller class. There is a parameter annotated with `@PathVariable`. There is another parameter annotated with `@RequestBody` `@Valid`. The problem is RequestBody is getting validated first and the method returns in case of exception. But I want `@Pathvariable` to be validated first and return in case of exception.

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/order", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class OrderMappingController {

    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}/order-mapping", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> UpdateOrderMapping(@PathVariable(value = "id") @NotBlank(message = "InvalidID")
                                                @ValidOrderId String id,
                                                @RequestBody @Valid OrderMappingRequest request) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom annotation and validator to validate the @Pathvariable

```
@RestController
    @Validated
    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/order", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public class OrderMappingController {
    
            @PutMapping(value = "/{id}/order-mapping", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public ResponseEntity<?> UpdateOrderMapping(@PathVariable(value = "id") @OrderId  String id,
                                                        @RequestBody @Valid OrderMappingRequest request) {
                //...
            }
        }
```

Create custom annotation OrderId  which can validate with custom validator class OrderIdValidator

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = OrderIdValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD,PARAMETER })
public @interface OrderId{
    public String message() default "order id not found ";
    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};
}
```

Then you can write the custom validator class which can check the business logic if the id is present in db or any other validation

```
public class OrderValidator implements ConstraintValidator<OrderId, String> {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository repository;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            return (repository.existsByPeriod(value));

    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I have done exactly. But I need the Pathvariable validation to happen first. Is there anyway to make OrderId to be validated first and return error message to client?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try a different approach. Try not to annotate @Valid on your OrderMappingRequest, then implement a custom [org.springframework.validation.Validator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) for your OrderMappingRequest bean which will then be injected and invoke in your OrderMappingController#UpdateOrderMapping method.

```
public class OrderMappingController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderMappingRequestValidator validator

    @PutMapping("/{id}/order-mapping")
    public ResponseEntity<?> UpdateOrderMapping(@PathVariable 
                                                @NotBlank(message = "InvalidID")
                                                @ValidOrderId String id,
                                                @RequestBody OrderMappingRequest request,
                                                BindingResult result) {
        
       validator.validate(request, result);

       if(result.hasErrors()){
          ... do stuff or throw
       }

    }
}
```